# Print PDF document on client side silently

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0

I have been searching for a few days how to print PDF documents on the client side. I tried some code shown online, but that yielded no result.

On further search, some says Adobe doesn't allow such method, or can't be done because of security issues, etc ...

I have following questions:

1. Whole scenario of printing PDF on the client side silently and issues related to it.
2. Any genuine approach to achieve it? OR other alternative?

I need detailed yes or no for my management.

Comment: You could use ghostscript for printing the PDF.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524323/print-pdf-using-ghostscript

Comment: Do you need this to work for PDF files that are distributed outside your organization? If not, and this is an internal only solution, do you have control over the desktops and devices? I other words, can your IT department control which PDF viewer is used to open the file and can they push configurations files and/or registry changes to those machines?

Comment: If you *need detailed yes or no*, you should start by detailed requirements yourself. In particular, which PDF viewers are used at the current side, and can you manipulate the configuration of those viewers. You definitively won't find a solution working for all existing PDF viewers, and you'll need some influence on the client compute to make things work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can silent print any PDF with the **free library PDFium**, and any other not free library is pure scam. Just add the PDFium free library to your project by using NuGET and here is de code in an static method:

```
public static void PrintFileWithPDFium(string file, string printer_name, short copy_number = 1)
{
    // Create the printer settings for our printer
    PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = printer_name,
        Copies = copy_number,
    };
    // Now print the PDF document
    using (PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file))
    {
        using (PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocument.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;
            //printDocument.DefaultPageSettings = pageSettings;
            printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocument.OriginAtMargins = false;
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Any issues just comment this post, I'm glad to help you with this